# Opening SQLite VSIX (VS Extension)

Tags: sqlite, windows-8

Today I attempted to open the SQLite vsix (visual studio extension, [found here](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html)) so that I can add its capability to a Windows 8 store app.

For some reason though Windows 8 had not properly associated VSIX extensions with Visual Studio 2012 and it kept opening it as a compressed file, not exactly the result I expected.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the issue I choose "open with" by right-clicking on the VSIX file and choose the following VSIX Launcher that comes with VS2012:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\VSIXInstaller.exe

Now the VSIX file opens correctly and installs into VS2012. This technique should resolve it for anyone who hits the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the .zip file to .vsix and install as usual.